# Spring-cloud kafka stream schema registry

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to transform with functionnal programming (and spring cloud stream) an input AVRO message from an input topic, and publish a new message on an output topic.
Here is my transform function :

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, Data>, KStream<String, Double>> evenNumberSquareProcessor() {
    return kStream -> kStream.transform(() -> new CustomProcessor(STORE_NAME), STORE_NAME);
}
```

The CustomProcessor is a class that implements the "Transformer" interface.

I have tried the transformation with non AVRO input and it works fine.

My difficulties is how to declare the schema registry in the application.yaml file or in the the spring application.

I have tried a lot of different configurations (it seems difficult to find the right documentation) and each time the application don't find the settings for the schema.registry.url. I have the following error :

> Error creating bean with name 'kafkaStreamsFunctionProcessorInvoker':
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required
> configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.

Here is my application.yml file :

```
    spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: evenNumberSquareProcessor
      bindings:
        evenNumberSquareProcessor-in-0:
          destination: input
          content-type: application/*+avro
          group: group-1
        evenNumberSquareProcessor-out-0:
          destination: output
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kafka:9092
          consumer-properties:
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
```

I have tried this configuration too :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: my-cluster-kafka-bootstrap.kafka:9092
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
              default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
          bindings:
            evenNumberSquareProcessor-in-0:
              consumer:
                destination: input
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
            evenNumberSquareProcessor-out-0:
                destination: output
```

My spring boot application is declared in this way, with the activation of the schema registry client :

```
    @EnableSchemaRegistryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class TransformApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransformApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you could bring to me.

Regards
CG

Answer (score 1):

Configure the schema registry under the `configuration` then it will be available to all binders. By the way. The avro serializer is under the `bindings` and the specific channel. If you want use the default property `default.value.serde:`. Your Serde might be the wrong too.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost:9092
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
              default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
          bindings:
            process-in-0:
              consumer:
                valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

Don't use the `@EnableSchemaRegistryClient`. Enable the schema registry on the Avro Serde. In this example, I am using the bean `Data` of your definition. Try to follow [this example here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-avro).

```
@Service
public class CustomSerdes extends Serdes {

    private final static Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Stream.of(
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    public static Serde<Data> DataAvro() {
        final Serde<Data> dataAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        dataAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        return dataAvroSerde;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have adapted the application.yml configuration to my needs...But unfortunately, I always have the same error. Is there something else wrong in my spring-boot application? Regards CG

Comment: I added an Avro custom Serde. But I suggest you look at the link that I added

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by « you don’t need avro »? Is the registry declaration not necessary (in configuration or on Serde) when we use the java type directly?

Comment: Oh. My bad. Now I see that `Data` is your avro bean. I saw Double instead of `Data`. i edited the post to use your `Data` bean.